# Expectation of a random quadratic form

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, random-matrices, multivariate-statistical-analysis

Let ${\bf X}_{1},\cdots,{\bf X}_{p}$ be $p$ independent Gaussian random variables, in particular, ${\bf X}_{j}\sim N_{n}({\bf 0},\lambda_{j} {\bf I})$, where $\lambda_{j}$s are not all equal, $j=1,\ldots,p$, $n<p$.

Define ${\bf W}=\sum_{j=1}^{p} {\bf X}_{j}{\bf X}_{j}^{\top}$. I am interested in finding the expectation of ${\bf X}_{j}^{\top} {\bf W}^{-1} {\bf X}_{j}$.

Any idea towards solving this would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Do these random variables take real values (which their name suggests) or values in some vector space (which the transpose symbol suggests)?

Comment: The random variables take values in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, where $n<p$.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the expectation is given by a relatively simple form? Even when $n=1$, the expectation reduces to $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda_j}{1+2\lambda_j t}\prod_{k=1}^{p}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2\lambda_k t}}\,\mathrm{d}t.$$ This seems not admitting an elementary closed form for $p\geq3$. (For example, if $p=3$ then this evaluates to an expression involving elliptic functions.)

Comment: No, I am not sure if a simple form exists at all.

Comment: Not sure that $\mathbf{W}^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: It exists almost surely as $p>n$, and ${\bf X}_{j}$s are mutually independent.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $W_1=\sum_{i=2}^pX_iX_i^T$ and $Y=W_1^{-1/2}X_1$. Then $$Y^TY=\|Y\|^2=X_1^TW_1^{-1}X_1=\mathrm {trace}\, (W_1^{-1}X_1X_1^T)$$ and
$$X_1^TW^{-1}X_1=Y^T(I+YY^T)^{-1}Y=Y^T\left(I-\frac{YY^T}{1+\|Y\|^2}\right)Y=\frac{\|Y\|^2}{1+\|Y\|^2}.$$ We have also from the independence $$E(\|Y\|^2)=\mathrm {trace}\,( E(W_1^{-1})E(X_1X_1^T))=\lambda_1\mathrm {trace}\, E(W_1^{-1}).$$Difficult to say more without further hypothesis on the lambdas. Recall that the expectation of the inverse of a Wishart matrix is known, therefore at least $E(\|Y\|^2)$ is computable if $\lambda_2=\ldots=\lambda_p.$

Comment: Thank you! I got same simplification by applying Woodbury matrix identity of $\left({\bf X}_{1} {\bf X}_{1}^{\top}+{\bf W}_{1}\right)^{-1}$, and then could not proceed.